# Inconsistent IN and NOT IN subquery results

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, sqlite, subquery

I have three tables: patients, chats and salesforce_leads. I want to find all of the emails in chats that do not exist in the other two tables. My first attempt returned 0 and I'm very confused as to why. Below are the queries and their results:

**Query 1:** first attempt with unexpected results

```
SELECT CouNT(DISTINCT LOWER(chat_email)) FROM chats 
WHERE LOWER(chat_email) NOT IN (
 SELECT LOWER(email) FROM patients 
 UNION ALL 
 SELECT LOWER(lead_email) FROM salesforce_leads)
[ { 'COUNT(DISTINCT LOWER(chat_email))': 0 } ]
```

Result: 0

Naturally unsatisfied with this answer, I tried the following:

**Query 2:** How many exist in both?

```
SELECT CouNT(DISTINCT LOWER(chat_email)) FROM chats 
WHERE LOWER(chat_email) IN (
 SELECT LOWER(email) FROM patients 
 UNION ALL
 SELECT LOWER(lead_email) FROM salesforce_leads)
[ { 'COUNT(DISTINCT LOWER(chat_email))': 701 } ]
```

Result: 701

**Query 3:** How many unique emails?

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT LOWER(chat_email)) FROM chats
[ { 'COUNT(DISTINCT LOWER(chat_email))': 1059 } ]
```

Result: 1059

So I would've expected the result from query 1 to be 358 (1059 - 701). I finally was able to get this result performing query 4 below, but I don't understand why.

**Query 4:** achieves expected result, but it's not pretty and uses an extra subquery.

```
SELECT CouNT(DISTINCT LOWER(chat_email)) FROM chats 
WHERE LOWER(chat_email) NOT IN (
 SELECT DISTINCT(LOWER(chat_email)) FROM chats 
 WHERE LOWER(chat_email) IN (
  SELECT LOWER(email) FROM patients 
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT LOWER(lead_email) FROM salesforce_leads))
[ { 'COUNT(DISTINCT LOWER(chat_email))': 358 } ]
```

Can someone explain to me why might query 1 not equal the result of query 4?

This is using node.js and sqlite3.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. I get the same results from 1 and 4: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/10cc18/2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Never* use `NOT IN` with subqueries.  It does not behave the way that you expect.  If any value returned in the subquery is `NULL`, then all rows are filtered out.

Instead, use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT LOWER(c.chat_email))
FROM chats c
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM patients p WHERE LOWER(p.email) = LOWER(c.chat_email)
                 ) AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM salesforce_leads sf WHERE LOWER(sf.email) = LOWER(c.chat_email)
                 ) ;
```

I broke the logic into two subqueries, simply because using `union`/`union all` in such subqueries generally gets in the way of optimization.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I wasn't aware of that behavior with null values. I was able to get the query to work by removing the null emails from the subqueries (WHERE email IS NOT NULL). Also, I ran the query you wrote with NOT EXISTS because I wanted to understand it better. Basically, it's running two subqueries for each row in chats. To make sure that IN and NOT IN don't work the same way, I ran them both: NOT IN took <1 second and NOT EXISTS took 10 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Are you suggesting that `NOT IN` does not work properly? Because lately I have been left with the impression that this might be so. In my case *(previously discussed in a thread a few weeks ago that I haven't found yet),* I was looking for `article_revisions` that were `NOT IN` a table of `articles` ... note that none of these values are `NULL` ... and I always come up with "nothing," which is wrong.

Whereas, an `IN` query produced the list of values that did match.

So – at least it seems to me – `IN` works, but `NOT IN` doesn't.

Gordon, is this your experience also? Are you saying that I should try `NOT EXISTS`?